# Hadoop job submission using Apache Ignite Hadoop Accelerators

Tags: hadoop, ignite

Disclaimer: I am new to both Hadoop and Apache Ignite. sorry for the lengthy background info.

**Setup**:
I have installed and configured Apache Ignite Hadoop Accelerator. Start-All.sh brings up the below services. I can submit Hadoop jobs. They complete and I can see results as expected. The start all uses traditional core-site, hdfs-site, mapred-site, and yarn-site configuration files.

```
28336 NodeManager
28035 ResourceManager
27780 SecondaryNameNode
27429 NameNode
28552 Jps
27547 DataNode
```

I also have installed Apache Ignite 2.6.0. I am able to start ignite nodes,  connect to it using web console. I was able to load the cache from MySQL and run SQL queries and java programs against this cache.

For running Hadoop jobs using ignited Hadoop, I created a separate ignite-config directory, in which I have customized core-site and mapred-site configurations as per the instructions in the Apache ignite web site.

**Issue**:
When I run a Hadoop job using the command:

```
hadoop --config  ~/ignite-conf jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.0.jar wordcount input output1
```

**I get the below error** (Note, the same job ran successfully against the Hadoop/without ignite):

java.io.IOException: Failed to get new job ID.

...
...

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.client.GridClientDisconnectedException: Latest topology update failed.
...
...

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.client.GridServerUnreachableException: Failed to connect to any of the servers in list: [/:13500]

...
...

It looks like, there was attempt made to lookup the jobtracker (13500) and it was not able to find. From the service list above, it's obvious that job tracker is not running. However, the job ran just fine on non-ignited hadoop over YARN.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved in my case.
The job tracker here meant the Apache Ignite memory cache services listening on port 11211.
After making this change in mapred-site.xml, the job ran!